# Unexpected token, expected , (28:0), when coding React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm coding my first test app with react-native but I cant get my syntax to work. I dont get this, where Am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class Form extends React.Component ({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      userEvent : ""
    }
  },

  handleChange: function(e){
    this.setState({
      userEvent = e.target.value
    })
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h2>{this.userEvent}</h2>
      <input type="text" value={this.state.userEvent} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is where code states it is expecting ",":

```
export default class App extends Component {
```

Any tips?

```
render() {
    return (
      <Form />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `export default class App extends Component` why are you just using `extends Component` instead of `React.Component` as you are just importing `React`

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't use `this.setState` properly. `this.setState` takes an object or a function that returns an object as input. `{userEvent = e.target.value}` is not valid JavaScript...

```
handleChange: function(e){
  this.setState({
    userEvent: e.target.value,
  })
}
```

Second, you also forgot to close you `Form` Component:

```
render() {
    return (
      <Form />
    );
  }
}
```

You added ',' after your functions `getInitialState` and `handleChange`

Removed the parenthesis after `React.Component`

Added the bind for the `handleChange` function

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  getInitialState(){
    return {
      userEvent: ""
    }
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      userEvent: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.userEvent}</h2>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.userEvent} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Edit: Answer to your answer

You have an error stating that it does not find the variable `Component` is because as stated by @Aaqib, you use

```
export default class App extends Component {
```

Instead of

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
```

Comment: I edited those, it still gives the same error, expecting ",".

Comment: Hmm, now when i removed them, it keeps saying it expected them?

Comment: Can you try with the new edited code ? I made several modifications

Comment: `setState` should return a mapping, not an assignment, i.e. `this.setState({ userEvent: e.target.value });`.

Comment: Oh yeah Parker, missed that one, I'm going to edit that

Comment: I tried with edited code. Now it doesn't give any syntax errors, but rather expo says that it cant find the variable: Component.

Comment: It is because you use `export default class App extends Component {` instead of `export default class App extends React.Component {`

Comment: "First, you don't use this.setState properly. You should use with brackets:' No... `setState` just takes an object or a function that returns an object as input "You should use brackets" is a poor explanation

Comment: @Maxwelll edited accordingly, thanks for being more precise, getting too late :)